# How do I produce a table of converted coordinates from Equatorial to AltAz?

Tags: python, numpy, coordinate-systems, astropy, healpy

I have tried debugging my code and I've realised that ultimately it breaks down when I try to save my AltAz coordinates into a .csv file because its not a numpy array, its a SkyCoord object. Could someone suggest a simple of way of converting a large table of Equatorial coordinates to AltAz or how I can get my code to save to file.

```
 # Get time now
time = astropy.time.Time.now()
time.delta_ut1_utc = 0

# Geodetic coordinates of observatory (example here: Munich)
observatory = astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation(
    lat=48.21*u.deg, lon=11.18*u.deg, height=532*u.m)

# Alt/az reference frame at observatory, now
frame = astropy.coordinates.AltAz(obstime=time, location=observatory)
# Look up (celestial) spherical polar coordinates of HEALPix grid.
theta, phi = hp.pix2ang(nside, np.arange(npix))
# Convert to Equatorial coordinates
radecs = astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord(
    ra=phi*u.rad, dec=(0.5*np.pi - theta)*u.rad)

# Transform grid to alt/az coordinates at observatory, now
altaz = radecs.transform_to(frame)
#Transpose array from rows to columns
altaz_trans=np.transpose(altaz)

np.savetxt('altaz.csv',altaz_trans,fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: `np.savetxt` is fairly primitive, and astropy has better options built in for dealing with the sorts of text files astronomers like to make. The answer below discusses a couple decent alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`to_string()`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.html#astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.to_string) method on `altaz`. That will give you a list of strings, each entry of which is has an altitude an azimuth number (they are separated by a space, so you can `.split()` them or whatever). Then you can write it out with numpy or your other library of choice.

Alternately, if you want to go straight to a file, you can create an astropy [`Table`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/), and have columns `'alt'` and `'az'` that you respectively set equal to `altaz.alt` and `altaz.az`. Then you can `.write(format='ascii')` that table.